# Download subset of objects in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a site with a search page with a number of forms, and a page to display the results of the search. I want the users to be able to download the results of the search (as a text file or whatever).

This is basically what my view looks like:

```
def search_page(request):
    form = SearchOptions()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #filter the objects based on the input in the forms
        return render_to_response('results.html', {'filtered_objects' : filtered_objects}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    else:
        return render_to_response('search_page.html', {'form' : form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The ideally, I would like another view for handling downloads, something like

```
def download(filtered_objects):
    #process file
    return downloadable_file
```

I have a download view that works (it lets me download a dummy file), but I don't know how to pass filtered_objects to it.

Answer (score 2):

You could define an utility search function that returns the search results based on the search parameters ; and leave it up to the views to call this function and handle how the result should be presented (html or csv download or json or whatever).

Alternatively, you could add a parameter (in the url or as a get parameter) to your view that would define the output format and return the appropriate response. Be wary of invalid parameters though.

Comment: I was considering creating a separate search function, but wouldn't I need to filter the objects twice then (once for displaying them on the page, and once when downloading)? If possible, I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: Then you would need to store the result somehow and allow the user to retrieve it. That is, you're looking into caching. You might want to generate a unique key for the search (based on a hash of the search params, for instance), and a timestamp if you want time-based invalidation. You can then store the result of the search (or the associated items PKs) in cache (memcached, or in your request.session if you want an easier approach) and then put that cache key in a form or as a get parameter that you pass your csv export view.

Answer (score 0):

Is it enough to export the result of your query as a CSV file?

Try this and see if it fits to what you want to do:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-csv/?from=olddocs

Comment: CSV would be acceptable but not ideal. But does that answer how I get access to my filtered objects in a different view?